# Copying a PyTorch Variable to a Numpy array

Tags: numpy, deep-learning, pytorch, tensor

Suppose I have a PyTorch Variable in GPU:

```
var = Variable(torch.rand((100,100,100))).cuda()
```

What's the best way to **copy** (not bridge) this variable to a NumPy array?

```
var.clone().data.cpu().numpy()
```

or

```
var.data.cpu().numpy().copy()
```

By running a quick benchmark, `.clone()` was slightly faster than `.copy()`. However, `.clone()` + `.numpy()` will create a PyTorch Variable plus a NumPy bridge, while `.copy()` will create a NumPy bridge + a NumPy array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a very interesting question. According to me, the question is little bit opinion-based and I would like to share my opinion on this.

From the above two approaches, I would prefer the first one (use `clone()`). Since your goal is to copy information, essentially you need to invest extra memory. `clone()` and `copy()` should take a similar amount of storage since creating numpy bridge doesn't cause extra memory. Also, I didn't understand what you meant by, [copy()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.copy.html) will create two numPy arrays. And as you mentioned, `clone()` is faster than `copy()`, I don't see any other problem with using `clone()`.

I would love to give a second thought on this if anyone can provide some counter arguments.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I edited my question to clarify the "two numpy" parts.

Answer (score 0):

Because `clone()` is [recorded by AD](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/copy-deepcopy-vs-clone/55022) second options is less intense. There are [few options](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63963828/5884955) you may also consider.